# Define html in css

Tags: html, css

I have this element on my wordpress website, could you please tell me how to define it in my style.css?

```
<div id="wpforms-180-field_22-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-textarea order-width" data-field-id="22">
```

Like  `.wpforms-180-field_22-container #...`

Sorry I just can´t get it right, thank you so much for your help!

Kind regards,
Griffith

Comment: the answer given by nourza is right. but you are struggling with basic css.

Answer (score 1):

To define class in the css you should put . before the name. To define the id you should put # before the name.
You can add anyone  of this to your css file and to put what you want inside it. for example background color is red

```
   .wpforms-field{
     background-color:red;
    }
```

OR

```
   .wpforms-field-textarea{
     background-color:red;
   }
```

OR

```
.order-width{
  background-color:red;
 }
```

OR

```
#wpforms-180-field_22-container{
  background-color:red;
 }
```